# Gulp deploy ftp to production

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-ftp, vinyl-ftp

I am using some gulp task to deploy to production, but i have problem with gulp-deploy, i need some other files form other folder to be copied on diferrent location on server this is my task

```
//Gulp APP ftp deploy
gulp.task('deploy-app', function () {

    var conn = ftp.create({
        host: 'xxx',
        user: 'xxx',
        password: 'xxx',
        parallel: 10,
        log: gutil.log
    });

    var globs = [
        './css/**/*{css,png,jpg,gif,ttf,woff,eof,svg,woff2}',
        './img/**',
        './views/**',
        './scripts/**',
        'index.html',
        'Web.config'
    ];

    // using base = '.' will transfer everything to /public_html correctly 
    // turn off buffering in gulp.src for best performance 

    return gulp.src(globs, { base: '.', buffer: false })
        .pipe(conn.newer('/site/wwwroot')) // only upload newer files 
        .pipe(conn.dest('/site/wwwroot'));

});
```

The problem I have here is that i dont need **index.html** from root, because i have another **index.html** that is inside folder **dist** but it has to go in root of the server folder, how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`gulp-if`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if) in combination with [`gulp-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) to change only the destination directory for your `index.html` file without affecting any of the other files:

```
var gulpIf = require('gulp-if');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('deploy-app', function () {

    var conn = ftp.create({
        host: 'xxx',
        user: 'xxx',
        password: 'xxx',
        parallel: 10,
        log: gutil.log
    });

    var globs = [
        './css/**/*{css,png,jpg,gif,ttf,woff,eof,svg,woff2}',
        './img/**',
        './views/**',
        './scripts/**',
        './dist/index.html',
        'Web.config'
    ];

    return gulp.src(globs, { base: '.', buffer: false })
        .pipe(gulpIf('dist/index.html', rename({dirname:''})))
        .pipe(conn.newer('/site/wwwroot')) 
        .pipe(conn.dest('/site/wwwroot'));
});
```